# Can the ivar variable created automatically by properties accessible by the child class?

Tags: objective-c

I think so. _iVar is protected.

Yet, I have to add these to child classes:

```
@synthesize strFullName = _strFullName;
@synthesize strPictureURL = _strPictureURL;
@synthesize strID = _strID;
@synthesize strFirstName = _strFirstName;
@synthesize strLastName = _strLastName;
```

Otherwise my child classes do not have access to _strLastName, etc. Why?

the declaration on the super class is like these:

```
@interface BGTwitterOrFacebookHandler : BGMotherOfAllHandler
-(void) vRequestPermission;
@property (nonatomic,readonly) NSString * strID;
@property (nonatomic, readonly) NSString * strFullName;
@property (nonatomic,readonly) NSString * strPictureURL;
@property (nonatomic,readonly) NSString * strFirstName;
@property (nonatomic,readonly) NSString * strLastName;
@property (nonatomic,readonly) NSString * strBirthday;
@property (nonatomic,readonly) NSString * strEmail;
@property (nonatomic,readonly) NSString * strGender;
@property (nonatomic) ACAccountStore * ACAstore;
@property (nonatomic) ACAccount * acAcount;
+(BGTwitterOrFacebookHandler *) singleton;
-(void)logout;
@end
```

Comment: This has nothing to do with Xcode.

Comment: Besides; what's wrong with `super.prop = 123;`?

Comment: Sorry.... super.prop=123 won't work because the property is read only.